# how to show different menus dynamically on each item of a ListView in android by LongClicking on it?

Tags: android, android-listview, long-click

i want to show different menu on each item of a list view in android
it should check a status in clicked item list and decide to show which menu should show...

i dont know is it possible to do this or not
i mean to have more than one menu item for a single list view

for example two item is showing in listview
both items came from database

first item is to sell something
and the second is to buy something

so when i clicked on first item in listview it should show the menu related to sell items
and when i clicked on second item it should show the menu related to buy items

thanks in advance

Comment: This is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354807

Answer (score 0):

If you override onCreateContextMenu() you can edit the menu options in there, or dynamically build it.